# AngularJS - Binding element to blur not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple directive

```
app.directive('cell', function() 
{
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.bind('click', function()
            {
                element.addClass('selected');
            });

            element.bind('blur', function()
            {
                console.log('blur');
                element.removeClass('selected');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And my `cell` is

```
<div class="shift">
    <div class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in cells"></div>
</div>
```

The `click` binds fine, but the `blur` doesn't. It is never triggered!

Comment: Are you omitting your cell contents?  Blur only fires when a control has focus and loses it to another control.  If you can't use `TAB` to get to the control, it can't gain focus and there will be no blur event.  Usually only input type controls and buttons can get focus.

Comment: Okay okay, thanks! So is there a way to fire something up when you click anywhere outside of that element? That is without using `$document` cause that will just create an infinite number of events~

Comment: You can use `mouseleave` to detect when the mouse moves out of the element, but you'd have to register a click handler on the document and trigger the change when you detect a click that is not over that element.  What are you trying to do?  There may be a better way.  Off the top of my head I would think you could maintain a 'selectedCell' property on your scope and the ng-click on your div would just be `ng-click="selectedCell = cell"`.  Then on your div `ng-class="{selected : cell == selectedCell}"`

Comment: Do you need to set `selected` class when user click on element itself, or when user set focus on any input in cell?

Comment: This is suppose to be like an excel type cell. So upon clicking, I want to select the cell (just adding border). And when you click anywhere else (could be another cell, or somewhere else), I want to deselect the cell and remove the border

Comment: So, in each cell can be one or more input elements? And you can change  directive to add `selected` class when any input in cell got focus? I it's right?

Comment: if you got rid of using jQuery DOM approach you wouldn't be having this discussion. Think angular...model first. ng-clcik or ng-class would do what you want

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy, yes, there are one or more inputs inside each cell, which is why I want to refer to the div wrapper, and not an input tag.

Comment: @charlietfl, what other approach should I then do?

Comment: look at using `ng-click` ( set active item) and `ng-class` ( change class based on active item) and you won't need any document click handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you click on a `div`, it doesn't mean it gets keyboard focus. And if it doesn't get keyboard focus (as it is not editable), it can't lose it and thus can't `blur`.

An alternative approach could be the following:
Upon clicking on any `.cell` element, remove the `selected` class from every element that has it and then add it to the clicked element.

E.g.:

```
.directive('cell', function cellDirective($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function cellPostLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.on('click', onClick);
      scope.$on('$destroy', onDestroy);

      function onClick() {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(
            $window.document.querySelectorAll('.selected'),
            function (el) { angular.element(el).removeClass('selected'); });
        elem.addClass('selected');
      }

      function onDestroy() {
        elem.off('click', onClick);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZqSk/)**.

---

**NOTES:**

1. Depending on the browsers you are supporting and on whether you are using jQuery or not the code above might need modifications.
2. An alternative approach would be to register a `click`-listener on the document and remove the `selected` class from any element if the clicked element was a `.cell`. In that case, you need to take care to only register the listener once and not for every instance of `.cell`.
3. It is a good practise to always clean-up your listeners upon `scope`'s destruction, in order to prevent memory leaks. You can use `scope.$on('$destroy', callback)` to remove any event listeners registered on elements.

Comment: I was doing this originally. but the problem is that if I click on a cell, and then click somewhere else (i.e. not another cell), then the cell will not be deselected. And I  want it to be deselected.

Answer (score 0):

You  can handle chidlren `focus` and `blur` events in directive:

```
element.children().bind('focus', function() {
  element.addClass('selected');
});

element.children().bind('blur', function() {
  console.log('blur');
  element.removeClass('selected');
});
```